# Find and select local maxima on a raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, interpolation, filter

I'm trying in ArcGIS to obtain local maxima from a raster (for example a DEM) calculated with a circular sliding window of constant radius. Is there a way to pick up and select the local maximum points for each "window" to make interpolations?

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange. You need to ask for one solution per question, either by QGIS or ArcGIS.

Comment: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/how-focal-statistics-works.htm